# Assign returned type to a derrived type

Tags: c++

Can some one explain(/point me in) the right direction or give a simple example. I am using an API function and it returns a pointer of TYPE A. I have extended class A and I've called it B. B has one extra function.

How do I appropriately, assign/initialize the API returned pointer of TYPE A to an instance of B, so that I can call my extra function.

Comment: Give us a sample in code please. Usually you can simply use a `dynamic_cast<B*>(a);` to downcast to a derived class. But that's a sign of a flawed design.

Comment: Someone gave you a pointer to A but you want a B, right? You have to create a B yourself because nobody else knows how to. The fact that B extends A is unimportant. If you can make a B from A, go ahead and make it, otherwise tough luck.

Comment: How do I 'un-flaw' the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a proper constructor for your extended class, which accepts the base class and extend it the way you want to.

For example:

```
struct A {
    A(A& a) : a_(a.a_) {}
    A(int a) : a_(a) {}
    int a() { return a_; }
private:
    int a_;
};
struct B : A {
    B(A a) : A(a), b_(100) {}
    int b() { return b_; }
private:
    int b_;
};

A* thirdPartyFcn() {
    return new A(97);
}

int main()
{
    B b(*thirdPartyFcn());
    std::cout << b.a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.b() << std::endl;
}
```

*Note, that it expects that the base class has copy constructor.*

Answer (score 4):

The approach most people take is not to extend A to add a member function, but to simply add a new regular function that takes an argument of type `A&`. Member functions should *only* be used when you need access to a class's internals.

If you do need access to (protected) members, you can add a constructor for `B` that initializes the base class:

```
class B : A {
    B(A a) : A(std::move(a)) {}
}
```

and then just

```
B value = get_the_A();
```

This requires that `A` is copyable or movable. If not, then this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I do need to access the class's internals.

Comment: Do not think I can use this, the base class A, in the API does not accept an instance of itself. So, std::move(a) would be the same case?

Comment: What you're asking is impossible, then.

Comment: So, std::move(a) would be the same case since it is converting to an rvalue of a? <-- edit

Comment: I mis-understood.. But i've accepted the below answer. Thanks. ( edited : trying to make my reply more exact without assumptions )

Answer (score 0):

If your new function is not a virtual one, then simply `static_cast<B *>(functioncall())` would do it. It is **undefined behavior**, but it should work on all compilers. I don't recommend this method. Use this method only if you need to access the internals of `A`, and you don't have any other solution.

I recommend adding a simple standalone function, which takes `A *` as a parameter, instead of extending `A`.

Comment: At the moment, your solution - using a standalone function, which takes A * as a parameter, instead of extending A is the most 'stable' of solutions. I haven't found any easy to grasp articles on casting an instance or pointer instance, that doesn't involve undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm going with both your answers. static_cast, both are most appropriate.